# Kendo grid filter not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I've a kendo grid and when I click on filter, it is throwing a js error like below. Any idea why I'm getting this error? Also filter is not working integer values.

i.e I've a column with integer values, and when I click on filter and select equals to, it is not working.

Below is the screen

[image]

Here is the error when I try to filter integer values column

[image]

Comment: What jQuery version are you using, addBack is added in jQuery 1.8 (http://api.jquery.com/addback/)

Comment: Thank you, 1 issue got fixed but integer error is still there. I've updated my post. Please check

Comment: what is ResidentID data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addback) was added in jQuery 1.8, make sure you are on this version or more.